Getting PyperclipException in Langchain create_Dataframe_agent
Anyone encountered "PyperclipException" while working with langchain create_pandas_Dataframe_agent?
I am using the agent to work with my pandas dataframe. I have passed prompt to perform manipualtions but the agent is not able to read the dataframe. and gices the exception:
PyperclipException: 
    Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
    For more information, please visit
    https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#not-implemented-error
It seems that the clipboard functionality is not available in this environment. However, you can run the provided Python code in your local Python environment to achieve the desired result. 

I have used agent like this:
agent=create_pandas_dataframe_agent(ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.0),
                                        df, verbose=True,prefix=PREFIX,agent_type="openai-functions"
                                        )

Any help will be much appreciated.
